# Real-time retrieval of selected range in spreadsheet using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a apps script UI modal dialog with textbox and pick button. When I press pick button and select the range of cells in sheets, then it has to copy sheet range address location identified by sheet(0) or sheet(1). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cut or Copy and Paste

This is a cut and paste or copy and paste that use a modeless dialog so that you can make the selection even when the dialog is active.

```
function onOpen()
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Tools')
        .addItem('Copy or Cut', 'copyFromToSetupUi')
        .addItem('Display Properties','dispProperties')
        .addItem('Clear Ranges','clearCopyProperties')
        .addToUi();
}

function dispProperties()
{
  var copyProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var srcShtNameStr = copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetName');
  var srcShtRangeStr = copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetRange');
  var desShtNameStr = copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetName');
  var desShtRangeStr = copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetRange');
  var title = 'Copy From To Sheets Properties';
  var msg = 'Source Sheet Name = ' + srcShtNameStr + '<br />';
  msg += 'Source Sheet Range = ' + srcShtRangeStr + '<br />';
  msg += 'Destination Sheet Range = ' + desShtNameStr + '<br />';
  msg += 'Destination Sheet Range = ' + desShtRangeStr + '<br />';
  msg += '<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  dispStatus(title,msg);
}

function copyFromToSheets()
{
  var copyProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var srcRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetName')).getRange(copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetRange'));
  var srcA = srcRange.getValues();
  srcRange.setBackground('#ffffff');
  var desRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetName')).getRange(copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetRange'));
  desRange.setValues(srcA);
  desRange.setBackground('#ffffff');
}

function cutnpasteFromToSheets()
{
  var copyProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var srcRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetName')).getRange(copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetRange'));
  var srcA = srcRange.getValues();
  srcRange.clearContent();
  srcRange.setBackground('#ffffff');
  var desRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetName')).getRange(copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetRange'));
  desRange.setValues(srcA);
  desRange.setBackground('#ffffff');
}

function setCopySource()
{
  var srcShtName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var srcShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var copyProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  copyProperties.setProperty('SourceSheetRange', srcShtRange.getA1Notation());
  copyProperties.setProperty('SourceSheetName', srcShtName);
  srcShtRange.setBackground('#d9caa9');
}

function setCopyDestination()
{
  var desShtName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var desShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var copyProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  copyProperties.setProperty('DestinationSheetRange',desShtRange.getA1Notation());
  copyProperties.setProperty('DestinationSheetName', desShtName);
  desShtRange.setBackground('#c4df87');
}

function clearCopyProperties()
{
  var copyProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var srcShtNameStr = copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetName');
  var srcShtRangeStr = copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetRange');
  var desShtNameStr = copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetName');
  var desShtRangeStr = copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetRange');
  if(srcShtNameStr && srcShtRangeStr)
  {
    var srcShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(srcShtNameStr).getRange(srcShtRangeStr);
    srcShtRange.setBackground('#ffffff');
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('At least one of the Source String Properties is undefined in clearCopyProperties so background color cannot be reset.');
  }
  if(desShtNameStr && desShtRangeStr)
  {
    var desShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(desShtNameStr).getRange(desShtRangeStr);
    desShtRange.setBackground('#ffffff');
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('At least one of the Destination String Properties is undefined in clearCopyProperties so background color cannot be reset.');
  }
  copyProperties.setProperty('SourceSheetName', '');
  copyProperties.setProperty('SourceSheetRange', '');
  copyProperties.setProperty('DestinationSheetName', '');
  copyProperties.setProperty('DestinationSheetRange', '');
}

function copyFromToSetupUi()
{
  var copyProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var srcShtNameStr = copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetName');
  var srcShtRangeStr = copyProperties.getProperty('SourceSheetRange');
  var desShtNameStr = copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetName');
  var desShtRangeStr = copyProperties.getProperty('DestinationSheetRange');
  var title='No Title';
  var msg = 'No Text';
  if(!srcShtNameStr || !srcShtRangeStr )  //if !src
  {
    title = 'Select Source Range';
    msg = '<p>Please select input range from <strong>Source Sheet.</strong> and then press "Source Range Selected" button below.</p>\
    <br /><input type="button" value="Source Range Selected" onclick="google.script.run.copyFromToSetupHelper(1);google.script.host.close();" />';
    msg += '<script>console.log(\'flag1\');</script>';
    dispStatus(title, msg);
  }
  if ((srcShtNameStr && srcShtRangeStr) && (!desShtNameStr || !desShtRangeStr)) //if src and !des
  {
      var srcShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(srcShtNameStr).getRange(srcShtRangeStr);
      title = 'Select Destination Range';
      msg = '<p>Please select a destination range which is ' + srcShtRange.getNumRows() + ' rows by ' + srcShtRange.getNumColumns() + ' columns.</p>';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Destination Range Selected" onclick="google.script.run.copyFromToSetupHelper(2);google.script.host.close();" />';
      msg += '<br />Input Range: ' + srcShtRangeStr + '<br /><input type="button" value="Clear Ranges and Start Over" onClick="google.script.run.clearCopyProperties();google.script.host.close(); />';
      dispStatus(title, msg);
  }
  if((srcShtNameStr && srcShtRangeStr) && (desShtNameStr && desShtRangeStr))//if src and des
  {
    var srcShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(srcShtNameStr).getRange(srcShtRangeStr);
    var desShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(desShtNameStr).getRange(desShtRangeStr);
    if((desShtRange.getWidth()===srcShtRange.getWidth()) && (desShtRange.getHeight()===srcShtRange.getHeight()))
    {
      title= 'Displaying Source and Destination Ranges';
      msg = '<br />Source Sheet/Range: ' + srcShtNameStr + '/' + srcShtRangeStr + '<br />Destination Sheet/Range: ' + desShtNameStr + '/' + desShtRangeStr + '<br />';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Perform Copy" onclick="google.script.run.copyFromToSheets();google.script.host.close();" />';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Perform Cut & Paste" onclick="google.script.run.cutnpasteFromToSheets();google.script.host.close();" />';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Keep both Ranges Defined" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Clear Ranges and Start Over" onclick="google.script.run.clearCopyProperties();google.script.host.close();" />';
      dispStatus(title,msg);
    }
    else
    {
      var srcShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(srcShtNameStr).getRange(srcShtRangeStr);
      var desShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(desShtNameStr).getRange(desShtRangeStr);
      var newdesShtRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(desShtNameStr).getRange(desShtRange.getRow(), desShtRange.getColumn(), srcShtRange.getNumRows(), srcShtRange.getNumColumns());
      desShtRange.setBackground('white');
      newdesShtRange.setBackground('#c4df87');
      copyProperties.setProperty('DestinationSheetRange', newdesShtRange.getA1Notation());
      title = 'Destination Range Adjusted';

      msg = 'Source Range and Destination Range Dimension did not Match. So it was assumed that the upper left corner of the Destination Range is correct';
      msg += 'and that the Sheet Selections were correct. The Destination Range was modified to have the same dimensions as the Source Range. ';
      msg += '<br />Source Sheet/Range: ' + srcShtNameStr + '/' + srcShtRangeStr + '<br />Destination Sheet/Range: ' + desShtNameStr + '/' + newdesShtRange.getA1Notation() + '<br />';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Perform Copy" onclick="google.script.run.copyFromToSheets();google.script.host.close();" />';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Perform Cut & Paste" onclick="google.script.run.cutnpasteFromToSheets();google.script.host.close();" />';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Keep both Ranges Defined" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />';
      msg += '<br /><input type="button" value="Clear Ranges and Start Over" onclick="google.script.run.clearCopyProperties();;google.script.host.close(); />';
      dispStatus(title,msg);

    }


  }
}


function copyFromToSetupHelper(mode)
{
  var mode = (typeof(mode) !== 'undefined')? mode : 0;
  switch(mode)
  {
    case 1:
      setCopySource();
      copyFromToSetupUi();
      break;
    case 2:
      setCopyDestination();
      copyFromToSetupUi();
      break;
    default:
      clearCopyProperties();
  }
}
```

Here's the the dispStatus dialog.

```
function dispStatus(title,html,width,height)
{
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 400;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}
```